# Как написать скрипт для настройки PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

В докере установлена SQL. В ручную могу ее настроить - добавить пользователя, создать БД, таблицы. Как правильно это автоматизировать? думал напиать sh/py скрипт, но не понимаю как передать команду именно в postgres, а не в консоль. Может есть пример как добавить пользователя/БД/таблицу?

Или есть другие варианты кроме sh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Или есть другие варианты кроме sh?

А как раз sh варианта нет. Добавлять пользователей, создавать базы, таблицы - это всё `SQL`. Только `SQL`. Даже штатные консольные команды [`createdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createdb.html) или [`createuser`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createuser.html) лишь оболочки над соответствующей SQL командой.

Из sh можно вызвать что-то ещё, что отправит SQL команды. Например, [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)

```
psql -c "create database foo"
psql -f /path/to/file/with_SQL_commands
```

Если вам проще отправлять SQL из скрипта на питоне - используйте питон.

---

Конкретный образ может предлагать собственную готовую обвязку. [Например](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34753186), для `https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/` можно положить файлы с SQL командами в директорию `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`